# java code looping through an array

Tags: java

**why is my code here not working** im trying to print out every second number in the sequence as hello

```
public class Generalizations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            System.out.println(i);
        if (i%2==0){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put your sysout inside condition

Comment: This is one of the best scenarios where indenting your code would have pointed out the issue immediately

Comment: you forgot to cover if (i%2==0){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }  in for loop {} .. debug your code . you will know.

Comment: I am trying to print out the number sequence, and for every even number the words "hello" sorry for the bad layout. im new and didnt understand how it fully works

Comment: can someone post the solution please?

Comment: Seriously promoting your app afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print every second number as hello, you can try below looping :

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){            
        if (i%2==0){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }else{
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

To print every second element, print inside the condition as shown below:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {//esnure the brace here       
   if (i%2 == 0) {
       System.out.println(i);//prints every second element
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed the curly braces of for loop.

```
public class Generalizations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i%2==0){
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
public class Generalizations {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i%2==0){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the 'for' loop is missing the curly braces thus only one line below it is printed. If you want more than one statements to be executed in the 'for' loop, add a curly brace before the statements start and after your block of statements end. 
I believe your code does currently print one Hello though, doesn't it? That is because when the if statement runs the value of i is 10 thus fulfilling the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a curly brace at the start of your for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
```